# Find the probability of atleast two kings but none of the cards is of clubs.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two cards are drawn one by one from a pack of well shuffled cards with replacement.Find the probability of atleast two kings but none of the cards is of clubs.

---

Out of 52 cards there are 13 cards of clubs so the two cards must be drawn from remaining cards.The probability of a king being chosen is 3/52(as one king of club is to be omitted.)

I am stuck here.

Comment: Why do you say "at least" two kings?  If you are drawing two cards then you can't get more than two kings.

Comment: @lulu the writer clearly is not a native English speaker, and the phrase "at least" is unnecessary but not confusing.

Comment: You are correct so far. What is the probability, after drawing one king, of drawing a second one that is not the king of clubs?

Comment: @TheCount: I disagree. Language is more than formally correct or incorrect statements. We use clues like economic use of words like "at least" to orient ourselves as to whether we've correctly understood something. Including them when there's no reason to raises doubts about whether the mistake is here or perhaps somewhere else, and in this sense it is indeed confusing. lulu wasn't berating the OP, merely asking about this in order to clarify. It's in the OP's best interests to make the question as clear as possible.

Comment: @joriki I do not disagree with you, really. but we are mathematicians, and we can parse logic ("every elephant i own is green", for example, is confusing, but not untrue or even hard to understand after two or three readings). we know there are two options for what the phrase in the OP meant, and we can easily discern that neither changes the question. so we know what was meant. i don't think lulu was berating the OP, but i did worry that maybe lulu had missed some cues that english is not the OP's first language, and perhaps the OP was indeed doing their best.

Comment: @joriki That being said, i don't disagree with the fundamental point either of you are making, and i apologize to lulu if I came off as self-righteous, or if I indeed was self-righteous.

Comment: @TheCount  No worries.  To be clear:  my guess, actually, is that the OP intended to write "at least one king".  Of course, I might have that wrong.  That's why I asked for clarification.  All academic, as the OP seems disinclined to say anything further.